# MYSQL Sum: How to excludes all instances either one of two other columns are null

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, aggregation

In mysql, for each customer, I am trying to run a count that excludes all instances either one of two other columns are null. If there are no instances where both are null, then return 0.

Consider the following table:

[image]

Grouping by customer_id, for 22, it should return 9 because the only cost of the two row where blocked and unapproved are both null sums to 9. For 11, it should return 10 because all of row have double nulls. For 33, it should return 0 because there are no instances where blocked and unapproved are both null.

How would you recommend doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT customer_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN blocked IS NULL AND unapproved IS NULL THEN cost ELSE 0 END) total
FROM tablename
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Or:

```
SELECT customer_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(locked, unapproved) IS NULL THEN cost ELSE 0 END) total
FROM tablename
GROUP BY customer_id;
```